# have WP Gallery display the title instead of caption

Tags: gallery, title, customization

OK, I have looked and read quite a few message boards about this problem and I can not seem to find an answer.

I am uploading thousands of photos for a photographer and using the WP Gallery shortcode.  I do not want to manually input captions for every thumbnail, I want the image title to automatically populate that area.

How do I modify the Gallery output to make this change?

*edit*
here is a link to a gallery I have up.  The image titles are currently manually input into the caption field.
http://maryannerussell.com/afsp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick & dirty way, to set the title as caption, would be to use SQL (untested):

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_excerpt = post_title 
WHERE  
        post_excerpt    = '' 
    AND post_type       = 'attachment' 
    AND post_status     = 'inherit'
    AND post_mime_type  = 'image/jpeg'
    AND ID              = 123
```

Here we target the jpeg image with ID `123` and empty caption.

> Note I added the `ID = 123` and  `post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'` as extra
>   restrictions that you can adjust while testing.  Also remember to
>   adjust the table name of `wp_posts`.

WARNING: Backup your database before testing!

If you're looking for a dynamic way, then [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187917/possible-to-add-same-caption-to-all-photos-in-a-gallery/187938#187938) here might be related.

It might also be possible for you to add the caption while uploading your images:

```
/**
 * Automatically set the title as caption, when uploading an attachment.
 *
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188708/26350
 */
add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', function( $data, $postarr )
{    
    // Let's target only the uploading process and not the updating of attachments:
    if( empty( $data['post_excerpt'] ) && isset( $postarr['ID'] ) && 0 == $postarr['ID'] )
        $data['post_excerpt'] = $data['post_title'];

    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The quick and dirty way just saved me many hours of work tonight, thank you!  It solved my problem for today.
I am however looking for a dynamic way to solve the problem permanently.  Ultimately I will not be uploading her image galleries any longer, someone who will not have access to running SQL will.
I am hoping to find a hook or a function change that can always display the image name in place of the caption.

Comment: Great to hear that. How are you importing your images? @Donovan

Comment: I am using the wordpress media import.

Comment: Please check out my updated the answer @Donovan

Comment: this does add the image title as the caption but leaves the title blank, resulting in no image showing up in the gallery.    
http://postimg.org/image/hiyimfldx/
http://postimg.org/image/qs0owju9x/

Comment: I simplified it somewhat, let's see if this works ;-) @Donovan

Comment: upload photos and they now have the image title as the title and caption!  @birgire thank you for sticking with this.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @Donovan

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called `post_gallery` which allows you to create your own html for your gallery.  You could copy and edit the code from the `gallery_shortcode` function, (which creates the gallery code? and use that in the filter, with titles included/